# PySpark array_remove elements regex question

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to learn PySpark better and I'm streaming tweets and trying to capture the hashtags from the tweet's text (I know twitter API's json already provides the hashtags, I'm doing this as an excercise).

So with a pyspark dataframe named `Hashtags`,

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 18
-------------------------------------------
+--------------------+--------------------+
|               value|            Hashtags|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|Instead, it has c...|[instead,, it, ha...|
|  #iran #abd #Biden |[#iran, #abd, #bi...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I take the column "value", make it to lower case, split on whitespace/tab/newline thus creating an array column named "Hashtags", and then attempt to remove any elements with just whitespace, and any elements that don't begin with "#".

```py
Hashtags = Hashtags.withColumn("Hashtags", lower(Hashtags["value"]))
Hashtags = Hashtags.withColumn("Hashtags", split(Hashtags["Hashtags"], r'\s'))
Hashtags = Hashtags.withColumn("Hashtags", F.array_remove(Hashtags["Hashtags"], r'\s'))
Hashtags = Hashtags.withColumn("Hashtags", F.array_remove(Hashtags["Hashtags"], r'^(?!#).+'))
```

As far as I can tell, the `array_remove()` does remove elements with the regex `r'\s'` but it doesn't remove elements that don't begin with a "#".

I know the regex itself works outside of `array_remove()` because I tested it like this:

```py
RegText = r'^(?!#).+'
print(re.findall(RegText, "#AnandWrites"), re.match(RegText, "#AnandWrites"))
print(re.findall(RegText, "AnandWrites"), re.match(RegText, "AnandWrites"))
print(re.findall(RegText, "with\xe2\x80\xa6"), re.match(RegText, "with\xe2\x80\xa6"))
print(re.findall(RegText, "An#andWrites"), re.match(RegText, "An#andWrites"))
```

which gives me the following result, indicating that it successfully matches strings that don't begin with a "#"

```
[] None
['AnandWrites'] <re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='AnandWrites'>
['withâ\x80¦'] <re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='withâ\x80¦'>
['An#andWrites'] <re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='An#andWrites'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_remove` cannot be used with regex. You can consider using `filter` with `rlike` instead:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Hashtags', 
    F.expr(r"""
        filter(
            split(lower(value), '\\s'), 
            x -> x not rlike '\\s' and x not rlike '^(?!#).+'
        )
    """)
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------+---------------------+
|value            |Hashtags             |
+-----------------+---------------------+
|Instead, it has  |[]                   |
|#iran #abd #biden|[#iran, #abd, #biden]|
+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following udf (user defined function):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

def keep_hashtags(array):
    return [x for x in array if x.startswith("#")]

keep_hashtags_udf = udf(keep_hashtags, ArrayType(StringType()))

Hashtags = Hashtags.withColumn("Hashtags", keep_hashtags_udf(Hashtags["Hashtags"]))
```

This should give you the desired result. Also, check my blog: https://byambaa1982.github.io/2023/02/11/pysparkv4.html